# React. Having all extended components include className of the base class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Say, I have class MySpecialPanel which extends class Panel.
I want a css className "panel" appended to the className prop of root of MySpecialPanel by default, without me having to explicitly write it in every extended class.
How do I make it a part of a base class functionality?

Comment: You could use a [HOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why use Inheritance? Compositional patterns are far better for what you describe.

Include the MySpecialPanel class to your Panel class, and change your render to something like this:

```
render(){
    return (
            <div className="panel">
               <MySpecialPanel />
            </div>
           );
}
```